# React object fetched from API is missing properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am fetching a profile object from my API following user authentication. The fetch returns the profile object as expected, however my server logger clearly shows a profile object containing an "id" and "username", but the initial object returned to the client has only the "username". I am only able to access the "id" property of the profile abject after I refresh.

Not sure how to fix this, but I've tried everything I can think of...

**Login Form**

```js
export default class LoginForm extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
    onLoginSuccess: () => { }
    }

    state = { error: null }

    handleSubmitJwtAuth = ev => {
    ev.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ error: null })
    const { username, password } = ev.target

    //login request
    AuthApiService.postLogin({
      username: username.value,
      password: password.value,
    })
      //login response
      .then(res => {
        //updates context profile with username value after login
        this.props.updater({ username: username.value })
       
        username.value = ''
        password.value = ''
        TokenService.saveAuthToken(res.authToken)
        this.props.onLoginSuccess()
      })
      .catch(res => {
        this.setState({ error: res.error })
      })
}
```

**Profile API Service**

```js
const ProfileApiService = {
    getProfile() {
        return fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/profile`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `bearer ${TokenService.getAuthToken()}`
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                return (!res.ok)
                    ? res.json().then(e => Promise.reject(e))
                    : res.json()
            }
            );
    }
}
```

**(API) Profile Service**

```js
const ProfileService = {
    getProfile : (db,id) =>{
        return db
        .from('v_users')
        .select('id','username')
        .where({id})
        .first();
    },
    serializeProfile(profile){
        return {
            id: profile.id,
            username: xss(profile.username)
        };
    }
}
```

initially, `console.log(this.state.profile.id) //undefined`
after a refresh, `console.log(this.state.profile.id) // 7`
the server log shows this object being returned initially
`{ id: 7, username: 'qber83' }`, however as mentioned above, I am unable to access the "id" property without refreshing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here could be that your state is not updated properly, since the object returned is right the API services work, so here your context updater or `this.props.onLoginSuccess()` might contain the issue.